# Given a Python list, how to write a function that returns a given range of elements?

Tags: python, list

I have

```
def findfreq(nltktext, atitem)
    fdistscan = FreqDist(nltktext)
    distlist = fdistscan.keys()
    return distlist[:atitem]
```

which relies on FreqDist from the NLTK package, and does not work. The problem seems to be the part of the function where I try to return only the first n items of the list, using the variable `atitem`. So I generalize this function like so

```
def giveup(listname, lowerbound, upperbound)
    return listname[lowerbound:upperbound]
```

returning the usual error

```
>>> import bookroutines
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "bookroutines.py", line 70
    def giveup(listname, lowerbound, upperbound)
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

but hopefully also an answer from some kind person whose Python is much more fluent than mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a colon (`:`) at the end of the `def` line.

```
def findfreq(nltktext, atitem):
    fdistscan = FreqDist(nltktext)
    distlist = fdistscan.keys()
    return distlist[:atitem]
```

Python's function declaration syntax is:

```
def FuncName(Args):
    # code
```

Answer (score 0):

[`operator.itemgetter()`](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) will return a function that slices a sequence if you pass it a [`slice`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#slice) object.

Comment: Er, how does this help the OP? `.keys()` returns a list, which regular slice syntax works fine on.